# No pulse detection circuit

Tags: digital-logic, ltspice, phase-shift

I'm working on a circuit using two comparators which discretize two analogs signals (from 18 to 22 kHz). The circuit looks to detect the phase shift between signals by counting the number of pulses that each one of the comparators emits at ouput. Then, I send it to a R2R DAC to get an analog value. To achieve that, I use a counter that needs to reset in a specific moment.

This reset doesn't have fixed time because phase and frequency shifts, and what I think I need to do is to measure when the comparator stops sending pulses to emit that reset pulse.

[image]

As it can be seen in the LTSpice model, I need to reset the counter when the comparator briefly stop sending the pulses.

That's because I'm looking for a circuit which detects that there are no pulses in a certain treshold of time.

I attach the LTSPice Model where the reset pulse is fixed:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/be6k6jhx6h9ipo5/AACywKL40KTgJz2wyFPXie0sa?dl=1

Comment: So, you have this circuit that if it was correct someone could reverse engineer it to try and understand what you are trying to achieve but, it's not working right and there's no picture of it so I'm voting to close this question as being nonsense.

Comment: I attach the LTSpice Model! It's working but not as expected. I can't attach another picture because I don't have enough reputation. I don't understand why you say it's nonsense

Comment: Nobody in there right mind is going to open a zip file.

Comment: It is nonsense because you ask us to modify something that we don't see.

Comment: You can look it in Dropbox page, it is an .asc file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/be6k6jhx6h9ipo5/AACywKL40KTgJz2wyFPXie0sa?dl=0

Comment: @AugustoBonelliToro: We expect questions to be self contained and not cease to make sense once external links disappear. Besides, I don't currently have the ability to open such files.

Comment: I apologize. I upload the circuit model.

Comment: Why can't you use a type 1 or type 2 phase detector circuit?

Comment: Because I don't understand very well how to do it work. I checked it out, but still not getting it. Can you suggest me an IC for my application, please?

Comment: So, you need a retriggerable circuit, basically, which includes a time-out period? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @jonk You are right. I need that the reset-pulse triggers when the pulse train finishes. And it has to do before it starts again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely have no idea what is the machine which uses this circuit. But take a retriggerable monostable multivibrator. It resets your counter when there has existed no triggering during the pulse duration of the monostable.

Another option is to use a counter. Let's call it "X". It has a continuous clock input. Any pulses from your system reset the X. If the X gets no reset until it's last bit steps to Hi, that Hi is used to reset your counter and X, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to rethink your design and start with a spec and not a schematic.   Define the transfer function either by graph or equation  of what is required.

Right now you have a self clocking phase integrator which can create a sawtooth beat frequency of f /2^9  or roughly 40 Hz.

If you wanted an analog voltage of phase difference in 1 cycle, say so. THat is easy to do with a input signal converted to sawtooth with a sample and hold.

If you want a bipolar phase/frequency detector then use a '4046  Type II detector.

Make sense? Start question or design with list of functions or specs next time.

your schematic shows much learning needed.  Dont show Vcc lines, just use labels or a symbol.   Don't use a bunch of Flip flops when a '4020 exists, but dont use a ripple counter for phase integration, too many glitches from latency.